# How to convert RTSP streaming to Http Live Streaming using lighttpd?

Tags: ipad, rtsp, lighttpd, http-live-streaming

I'm having a problem here. I want to play RSTP streaming on ipad and iphone. but I find out that it will be much more easier if I use Http Live Streaming. I want to convert my RTSP streaming to Http live streaming using lighttpd. but I really have no idea how to do that. Do lighttpd accetp rtsp streaming url as input? Can anyone help? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you have two choices:

1) Run a server on your network that re-streams rtsp as hls.

a) wowza - popular, expensive
 b) live 555 - free, lots of work
 d) ffserver - free and as basic as it gets tons of work to make work.

Advantage :
No bandwidth restrictions over cellular or wi-fi
play with native apple players

Disadvantage

High server bandwidth - if your paying for server time you may want to watch this.
high letancy - forget any kind of live video.

2) Run FFmpeg based player on device

advantages :

a) A lot easier than it used to be, we do this all the time 
   b) deal with lgpl license, clear guidelines at ffmpeg.org and not a huge hassle
   c) all on device, no server load issues.

Disadvantages

Limited bandwidth over celluar (about 10 min intervals), unlimited over wifi

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd doesn't accept RTSP as an input. You will need some sort of translator program to read the rtsp stream and output the files to the website storage. I think you could do it with the avconv/ffmpeg program.

Comment: thank you for your information. Do you know how to run lighttpd on ios?

Comment: If you want to run it in the background, you'll need to jailbreak the device.